# How can I retrieve the JSON response from an AdalException?

Tags: adal

If I call AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken from our service, it throws an AdalException in a certain situation because the token I’m sending is missing a required claim.  The response from when I call AcquireToken contains JSON in it with the claim that is missing.  I want to be able to get at that JSON (specifically the missing claim information) so I can attempt to reauthorize the user with that missing claim.

Once I catch the AdalException from calling AcquireToken, how can I get at the JSON response to find out which claim was missing?  If I try to get the response stream from the innerException on the AdalException:

```
catch (AdalException ex)
{
    WebException webex = (WebException)ex.InnerException;
    WebResponse response = webex.Response;
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    ...
```

… then the responseStream I get has the CanRead, CanSeek, and CanWrite properties all set to false.  Consequently, I’m not sure how to retrieve the missing claims parameter since I can’t actually read from that stream.

Comment: What's the exact exception message you have got after you call `AcquireToken ` method? And please show us the code you are developing. We didn't send the claim to acquire the token, instead the Auzre AD require the parameters based [OAuth 2.0](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) authorization flow you were integrating.

Comment: Please help me know what part of the code you need to see. Auth code involving a client/service app can be thousands of lines. Which part is relevant here?  On the client, we call WebAuthenticationCoreManager.GetTokenSilentlyAsync(). That gives our app a token that we stuff into the Bearer HTTP header when calling our service. Our service reads the header (by calling ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext) and then passes it to AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken. That throws an exception with this message:

Comment: {"AADSTS50079: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor authentication to access '00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID: 9dd52cb2-f230-4782-9c5a-b6cc11cfd5b3\r\nCorrelation ID: d92e3da9-6bf2-446e-afc2-ca1e91d5edfe\r\nTimestamp: 2016-11-21 17:00:56Z"}.  The JSON response that we get from AAD has the missing claims parameter in it: claims=%7B%22access_token%22%3A%7B%22polids%22%3A%7B%22essential%22%3Atrue%2C%22Values%22%3A%5B%22d37c654b-b508-48ff-867c-77134090a605%22%5D%7D%7D%7D .

Comment: As far as I know, I need to get at that claims parameter (the one that indicates that MFA was used) so I can pass it back to our client and call RequestTokenAsync with that requested claim.  Of course, please let me know if I am misunderstanding any of these details.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this issue using the console application, however the it is not able to convert the `AdalException` to `WebException`.  Did I misunderstood? Did you want to retrieve the exception content? If so, is it helpful to get the message via `ex.InnerException.Message`?

Comment: What I ultimately need to do is get the value of the "claims" message from the JSON sent in the response when I called AcquireToken. I don't know how to do that, the only thing I have is an AdalException. Examining that, I see that the AdalException has an innerexception that is a WebException, so I guessed that perhaps I could get the response body content from there. As I mentioned above, I don't seem to be able to read from the stream. The InnerException.Message does not contain the response body, it just says "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: Based on my understanding, when the response is closed then it is not able to read the response stream. We can check the connection status via `((System.Net.ConnectStream)responseStream).IsClosed`. To fix this issue, I suggest you share the exact steps that we can reproduce this issue.

Comment: What more steps do you need besides the information I already provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to return the entire server JSON response is made in ADAL v3. Github Link :- https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/513
It is not yet available in ADAL v2.

Comment: For completeness, once you have v3, you can get at the JSON from the server from the AdalException using ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message (where ex is the AdalException)